# How does one manually convert Apollo Android-generated objects into JSON strings and back?

Tags: android, graphql, apollo, moshi

I use the [Apollo Android library](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android) to make queries to a GraphQL endpoint.
Everything works OK until I try to convert the results back to JSON strings (to store them in a [Room database](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room)). I naively tried to use [Moshi](https://github.com/square/moshi), however this fails with the following error:

> Cannot get available extra products: No JsonAdapter for interface com.example.MyQuery$MyFragmentInterface

where `MyFragmentInterface` in an interface generated by Apollo to handle query fragments.

So, I tried to find whether the Apollo library has/generates any conversion methods, i.e. sth like `toJson()`/`fromJson()`, for the generated models, however I couldn't find anything usable.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Apparently, there is a relevant issue in github which contains a possible workaround: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/1881#issuecomment-570817589

Answer (score 5):

Since Apollo 1.3.x there is an `Operation.Data.toJson()` extension function (Kotlin) and a corresponding `serialize` static method in Java.
Check https://www.apollographql.com/docs/android/advanced/no-runtime/#converting-querydata-back-to-json

For the opposite, Json string to `Query.Data`, I use something like the following:

```kotlin
fun String?.toMyData(): MyQuery.Data? {
    this ?: return null
    val query = MyQuery()
    val response: Response<MyQuery.Data> =
        OperationResponseParser(query,
                                query.responseFieldMapper(),
                                ScalarTypeAdapters.DEFAULT)
            .parse(Buffer().writeUtf8(this))
    return response.data
}
```

Comment: What about serialization? like converting the object of the generated class to json string?

Comment: Use `Operation.Data.toJson()` as I mention in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how you can deserialize string as generated object. Inlined comments for further details.

```kotlin
// Sample string response
val jsonResponse = """
{
  "data": {
  {
    "id": "isbn-889-333",
    "title": "Awesome title",
    "rating": 5
  }
}
""".trimIndent()

// Create query that is expect to return above response
val query = QueryBookDetails("book_id")

// convert string to input stream
val inputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(jsonResponse.toByteArray())

// Read bytes into okio buffer
val buffer = Buffer().readFrom(inputStream)

// Use the query to parse the buffer. 
val response = query.parse(buffer)

// response.data might be the one needed by you
```

Bear in mind that the response must honour the schema.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Postman` and see if the error also appears there https://blog.getpostman.com/2019/06/18/postman-v7-2-supports-graphql/

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. The error does not appear when apollo-graphql parses the JSON response to produce the models, neither when it does the reverse. Both work OK.
The error appears when *I* take the models and try to convert them to JSON, in order to store them as strings in my app's db (Room). I used moshi for that, but I suspect Gson or Jackson would produce a similar error.
Anyway, I finally succeeded in doing that based on this https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/1881#issuecomment-570817589, and I will write down a full answer when I get the chance.

Comment: Ok, did not get this, so this was a problem with serialization/deserialization...